# Transição ao usar hover - Como fazer um modo "reverso"?

Tags: css, css-hover, css-transições

Eis a transição:

```css
.subcont {
  width: 250px;
  height: 180px;
  background: purple;
}

.border1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  background: red;
  transition-delay: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.border2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 180px;
  background: red;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.border3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: 180px;
  background: red;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.border4 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 5px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  background: red;
  transition-delay: 0.9s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.subcont:hover>.border1 {
  height: 190px;
}

.subcont:hover>.border2 {
  width: 255px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

.subcont:hover>.border3 {
  height: 190px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.subcont:hover>.border4 {
  width: 255px;
}
```

```html
<div class="subcont">
  <div class="border1"></div>
  <div class="border2"></div>
  <div class="border3"></div>
  <div class="border4"></div>
</div>
```

Como é possível ver, ela altera a posição e o tamanho de certas divs para fazer com que apareça uma borda na div .subcont; o que eu gostaria de saber é: como criar um efeito reverso a esse? Digo, quando o usuário der hover na div .subcont esse efeito ocorre, mas como fazer com que, no momento que o usuário tirar o mouse de cima da div .subcont, esse efeito se reverta (desaparecer primeiro a div border4, depois a border3, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usei a pseudo class `:not` e inverti o valor do `transition-delay` testa agora

```css
          .subcont {
            width: 250px;
            height: 180px;
            background: purple;
          }
          
          .border1 {
            position: absolute;
            width: 5px;
            height: 0;
            margin-left: 250px;
            margin-top: -5px;
            background: red;
            transition-delay: 0;
            transition-duration: 0.3s;
          }
          
          .border2 {
            position: absolute;
            width: 0px;
            height: 5px;
            margin-left: 250px;
            margin-top: 180px;
            background: red;
            transition-delay: 0.3s;
            transition-duration: 0.3s;
          }
          
          .border3 {
            position: absolute;
            width: 5px;
            height: 0;
            margin-left: -5px;
            margin-top: 180px;
            background: red;
            transition-delay: 0.6s;
            transition-duration: 0.3s;
          }
          
          .border4 {
            position: absolute;
            width: 0;
            height: 5px;
            margin-left: -5px;
            margin-top: -5px;
            background: red;
            transition-delay: 0.9s;
            transition-duration: 0.3s;
          }
          
          .subcont:hover>.border1 {
            height: 190px;
            
          }
          .subcont:not(:hover)>.border1 {
            position: absolute;
            width: 5px;
            height: 0;
            margin-left: 250px;
            margin-top: -5px;
            background: red;
            transition-delay: 0.9s;
            transition-duration: 0.3s;
            
          }
          
          .subcont:hover>.border2 {
            width: 255px;
            margin-left: -5px;
          }
          .subcont:not(:hover)>.border2 {
            position: absolute;
            width: 0px;
            height: 5px;
            margin-left: 250px;
            margin-top: 180px;
            background: red;
            transition-delay: 0.6s;
            transition-duration: 0.3s;
          }
          
          .subcont:hover>.border3 {
            height: 190px;
            margin-top: -5px;
          }
          .subcont:not(:hover)>.border3 {
            position: absolute;
            width: 5px;
            height: 0;
            margin-left: -5px;
            margin-top: 180px;
            background: red;
            transition-delay: 0.3s;
            transition-duration: 0.3s;
          }
          
          .subcont:hover>.border4 {
            width: 255px;
          }
          .subcont:not(:hover)>.border4 {
            position: absolute;
            width: 0;
            height: 5px;
            margin-left: -5px;
            margin-top: -5px;
            background: red;
            transition-delay: 0s;
            transition-duration: 0.3s;
          }
```

```html
<div class="subcont">
    <div class="border1"></div>
    <div class="border2"></div>
    <div class="border3"></div>
    <div class="border4"></div>
</div>
```